# Long time to return from a method C++

Tags: c++, performance, time, ros

I am tracking the execution time of a method within itself and outside of the method. I am using ROS to get the time because this is all in a ROS package and it is just very convenient. The documentation can be found here: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time.

```
void ClassName::my_method()
{
  ros::Time t_start = ros::Time::now();
  // do stuff
  ros::Duration d_execution = ros::Time::now() - t_start;
}

void ClassName::Func()
{
  ros::Time t_total = ros::Time::now();
  my_method();
  ros::Duration d_total = ros::Time::now() - t_total;
}
```

The problem I have is that d_total is always significantly longer than d_execution.

d_execution will normally be 20-40 microseconds, but d_total will be around 150 microseconds.

I cannot figure out why this is happening. My understanding is that the only thing happening at the end of a method is deallocating any memory created on the stack in the method. However, I have re-written the code to only create around half the number of variables and I saw no change in d_total. What else can be happening to make the function take so long to return? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I measured the time for ros::Time::now() and it seems to be negligible.

```
  time_t now, then;
  time(&now);
  ros::Time t = ros::Time::now();
  time(&then);
  printf("t1-t0: %f", difftime(now, then));
```

The output is "t1-t0: 0.000000".

Also, all variables allocated on the stack in the method are doubles. The only exceptions are two std::vector's that only contain 2-3 elements.

Comment: How long does an empty method call take?

Comment: How many test run you did? Did you check assembler code?

Comment: How many tasks are you running in the background? The scheduler might cause for the delay.

Comment: note: destructors also executed "before function returns"

Comment: Have you timed `ros::Time::now()`?

Comment: @tadman An empty method is taking around 1 microsecond.

Comment: @VadimKey I have ran ~20. I am not running these tests in a testing framework. It is just running my code, and looking at the output.

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind I just had chrome running. When closed, there's no change.

Comment: Interesting. Sometimes computing the time itself can take random amounts of time depending on how that interfaces with your system clock.

Comment: @Lashane Ah, good to know! Thanks!

Comment: @alain I have not. I will do that.

Comment: Is `Func` a member of `ClassName`? If not, it's also helpful to know what object it's calling `my_method` on.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, Func is a member of ClassName. I just edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: @alain ros::Time::now() seems to take time that is less than a microsecond. I edited the post to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

How much difference will be with that exact version of my_method()?

Does my_method virtual?

When you are make performance tests it's a more natural way to show percentiles instead of averages.

This is would be more correct way to measure the difference:

```
void ClassName::my_method()
{
  ros::Time t_start = ros::Time::now();
  { // note this
  // do stuff
  } // and node this, destructors will be run before the next line
  ros::Duration d_execution = ros::Time::now() - t_start;
}
```

Under Linux/OSX you can try to use `clock_gettime()` what I usually use in performance tests. In C++ you can try std::chrono::duration (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). Probably ros::Time have a big time jittering.

Comment: Hi, I tried your approach and saw no change. Thank you for the info about how to correctly measure the difference though.

Answer (score 0):

Upon return, a method call destructors for everything declared in its topmost level.  These destructors may call more destructors, and so on.

Besides, upon return, the register values may be restored, however that would hardly take 100 microseconds.

Freeing the stack memory is done by changing the stack pointer value, which is very fast (probably one command).